# Multiple dock in one project with rswag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, documentation, rswag

I try to create 2 docs for my api. I have 2 namespaces in routes and I need to create 2 docs for my first namespace and second namespace. In request test they are divided on 2 folders. How can I automatically generate this 2 docs and what i need to write in routes file?

In routes I wrote 2 mounts for rswag engine, but I don't not what I need to do with my swagger.yml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time later I managed it something like this:

swagger_helper.rb:

```
docs = { 'v1/robots_api.yaml' => {
openapi: '3.0.1',
info: {
  title: 'API V1',
  version: 'v1'
},
paths: {},
components: {
  securitySchemes: {
    Bearer: {
      description: 'JWT key necessary to use API calls',
      type: :apiKey,
      name: 'Authorization',
      in: :header
    }
  }
},
servers: [
  {
    url: ENV.fetch('ROUTES_HOST'),
    variables: {
      defaultHost: {
        default: ENV.fetch('ROUTES_HOST')
      }
    }
  }
]
```

} }

```
if Rails.env.development?
  docs.merge!({ 'v1/swagger.yaml' => {
              openapi: '3.0.1',
              info: {
                title: 'API V1',
                version: 'v1'
              },
              paths: {},
              components: {
                securitySchemes: {
                  Bearer: {
                    description: 'JWT key necessary to use API calls',
                    type: :apiKey,
                    name: 'Authorization',
                    in: :header
                  }
                }
              },
              servers: [
                {
                  url: ENV.fetch('ROUTES_HOST'),
                  variables: {
                    defaultHost: {
                      default: ENV.fetch('ROUTES_HOST')
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            } })
end

config.swagger_docs = docs
```

config/initialaziers/rswag_ui.rb

```
Rswag::Ui.configure do |c|
  c.swagger_endpoint '/api-docs/v1/swagger.yaml', 'API V1 Docs' if Rails.env.development?
  c.swagger_endpoint '/<api_name>/api-docs/v1/<my_second_doc>.yaml', 'API V1 Docs <my api>'
end
```

And then I use rake rswag it generates for me 2 docs.